# Error 'Table '.\schema\table' already exists when adding foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have the following existing tables as seen here..

**show create table ExpeditedAddress;**

```
CREATE TABLE `expeditedaddress` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `stateProvince` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `zipPostal` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `brokerageId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `timezoneCode` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `productionFacilityId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `deliveryCutoffTime` time NOT NULL,
  `deliveredByTime` time NOT NULL,
  `daysToDeliver` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_ExpeditedAddress_Brokerage_ID` (`brokerageId`),
  KEY `FK_ExpeditedAddress_Country_StateProvince` (`country`,`stateProvince`),
  CONSTRAINT `ExpeditedAddress_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`brokerageId`) REFERENCES `brokerage` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `ExpeditedAddress_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`country`, `stateProvince`) REFERENCES `stateprovince` (`countryName`, `name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=149 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

which references this table

**show create table ProductionFacility;**

```
CREATE TABLE `productionfacility` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `stateProvince` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `zipPostal` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `timezoneCode` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `workingWeek` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_ProductionFacility_Country_StateProvince` (`country`,`stateProvince`),
  CONSTRAINT `productionfacility_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`country`, `stateProvince`) REFERENCES `stateprovince` (`countryName`, `name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Then when I try to add a foreign key to like this...

```
alter table ExpeditedAddress add foreign key FK_ExpeditedAddress_Productionfacility(productionFacilityId) references ProductionFacility(id);
```

I get the following...

```
[2012-08-09 15:39:22] [42S01][1050] Table '.\realtorprint_dev_prod\expeditedaddress' already exists
[2012-08-09 15:39:22] [HY000][1025] Error on rename of '.\realtorprint_dev_prod\#sql-1d74_710a' to '.\realtorprint_dev_prod\expeditedaddress' (errno: -1)
[2012-08-09 15:39:22] [42S01][1050] Table '.\realtorprint_dev_prod\expeditedaddress' already exists
```

Seems like a very odd error to get.  The types of the columns are both "bigint(20) not null".  Both tables are InnoDB.  The referenced column is a primary key.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Also, here is the result of running

**show engine InnoDB status;**

```
=====================================
120809 15:45:41 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 54 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 9322 1_second, 9321 sleeps, 846 10_second, 894 background, 894 flush
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 9323
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 520, signal count 520
Mutex spin waits 197, rounds 836, OS waits 12
RW-shared spins 499, rounds 14942, OS waits 498
RW-excl spins 2, rounds 242, OS waits 8
Spin rounds per wait: 4.24 mutex, 29.94 RW-shared, 121.00 RW-excl
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
120809 15:34:11 Transaction:
TRANSACTION 40CE, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting, thread declared inside InnoDB 485
mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
7 lock struct(s), heap size 1248, 16 row lock(s), undo log entries 7
MySQL thread id 28938, OS thread handle 0x16d4, query id 350923 localhost 127.0.0.1 rpuser copy to tmp table
alter table ExpeditedAddress add foreign key FK_ExpeditedAddress_Productionfacility(id) references ProductionFacility(id)
Foreign key constraint fails for table `realtorprint_dev_prod`.`#sql-1d74_710a`:
,
  CONSTRAINT `#sql-1d74_710a_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `productionfacility` (`id`)
Trying to add in child table, in index `PRIMARY` tuple:
DATA TUPLE: 15 fields;
 0: len 8; hex 8000000000000008; asc         ;;
 1: len 6; hex 0000000040ce; asc     @ ;;
 2: len 7; hex a3000005f90176; asc       v;;
 3: len 12; hex 536f757468204f6666696365; asc South Office;;
 4: len 25; hex 233235322c2031313438382d20323420537472656574205345; asc #252, 11488- 24 Street SE;;
 5: len 7; hex 43616c67617279; asc Calgary;;
 6: len 6; hex 43616e616461; asc Canada;;
 7: len 7; hex 416c6265727461; asc Alberta;;
 8: len 7; hex 54325a20344339; asc T2Z 4C9;;
 9: len 8; hex 8000000000000012; asc         ;;
 10: len 16; hex 416d65726963612f45646d6f6e746f6e; asc America/Edmonton;;
 11: len 8; hex 8000000000000001; asc         ;;
 12: len 3; hex 81adb0; asc    ;;
 13: len 3; hex 829810; asc    ;;
 14: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;

But in parent table `realtorprint_dev_prod`.`productionfacility`, in index `PRIMARY`,
the closest match we can find is record:
PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 11; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 8000000000000007; asc         ;;
 1: len 6; hex 00000000401f; asc     @ ;;
 2: len 7; hex b6000003a10176; asc       v;;
 3: len 16; hex 4461746147726f7570204c6f6e646f6e; asc DataGroup London;;
 4: len 21; hex 313837302043686561707369646520537472656574; asc 1870 Cheapside Street;;
 5: len 6; hex 4c6f6e646f6e; asc London;;
 6: len 6; hex 43616e616461; asc Canada;;
 7: len 7; hex 4f6e746172696f; asc Ontario;;
 8: len 7; hex 4e355620334537; asc N5V 3E7;;
 9: len 15; hex 416d65726963612f546f726f6e746f; asc America/Toronto;;
 10: len 0; hex ; asc ;;

InnoDB: Renaming table `realtorprint_dev_prod`.`#sql-1d74_710a` to `realtorprint_dev_prod`.`expeditedaddress` failed!
InnoDB: Renaming table `realtorprint_dev_prod`.`#sql-1d74_710a` to `realtorprint_dev_prod`.`expeditedaddress` failed!
InnoDB: Renaming table `realtorprint_dev_prod`.`#sql-1d74_710a` to `realtorprint_dev_prod`.`expeditedaddress` failed!
InnoDB: Renaming table `realtorprint_dev_prod`.`#sql-1d74_710b` to `realtorprint_dev_prod`.`expeditedaddress` failed!
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 40FD
Purge done for trx's n:o < 40F2 undo n:o < 0
History list length 827
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 40F3, not started
MySQL thread id 28939, OS thread handle 0x2ed8, query id 350949 localhost 127.0.0.1 rpuser
show engine innodb status
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: wait Windows aio (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: wait Windows aio (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: wait Windows aio (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: wait Windows aio (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: wait Windows aio (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: wait Windows aio (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: wait Windows aio (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: wait Windows aio (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: wait Windows aio (write thread)
I/O thread 9 state: wait Windows aio (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
 ibuf aio reads: 0, log i/o's: 0, sync i/o's: 0
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
1363 OS file reads, 17403 OS file writes, 4157 OS fsyncs
0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 0.11 writes/s, 0.11 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 0, seg size 2, 11 merges
merged operations:
 insert 11, delete mark 0, delete 0
discarded operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
Hash table size 1458971, node heap has 15 buffer(s)
3.54 hash searches/s, 12.39 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 121733086
Log flushed up to   121733086
Last checkpoint at  121601659
0 pending log writes, 0 pending chkp writes
2674 log i/o's done, 0.11 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total memory allocated 754434048; in additional pool allocated 0
Dictionary memory allocated 795806
Buffer pool size   44992
Free buffers       42494
Database pages     2483
Old database pages 896
Modified db pages  36
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 335, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 1352, created 1131, written 13915
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 2483, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
1 read views open inside InnoDB
Main thread id 7616, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 194766, updated 699, deleted 143, read 806318
2.74 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 2.74 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
```

Comment: `show engine innodb status` is always a good place to start, see if you've got an error there.

Answer (score 0):

If you look under your 'latest foreign key error', that long one complains that the foreign key you're trying to add is being violated: your existing data does not conform to the foreign key constraint.

(I'm not 100% sure that's what its saying, it may be complaining about index corruption, in which case you need to figure out how your index has become corrupt and rebuild the index, but I think not. I think they've just changed the foreign key violated error message since the last time I've seen it).